# What is a word that describes a person who takes up a challenge

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The same thing as the title. The situation is a person whose intent is against the protagonist's and is taking up a king's challenge.

I'm rewriting a fairytale from a different perspective. The fairytale being The 12 dancing princesses.

This has been answered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about 'challenger'?

Answer (score 1):

I would say a [***champion***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/champion). A champion loves being challenged because that's the way he gets to prove he is still a champion.

Also try [adventurous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adventurous), [bold](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bold) or [daredevil](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/daredevil).

Comment: But the champion has already succeeded.

Comment: @Nothingatall A champion could be ["someone who *fights* or speaks publicly in support of a person, belief, cause, etc."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/champion)

Comment: While I agree with you you ought to include the actual definition as well as the hyperlink in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "a contender" - a person or group competing with others to achieve something.

**Contender** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contender)

> a person who tries to win something in a contest; especially : a person who has a good chance of winning
>
> *"There are several contestants, but only two real contenders."*
> *"This latest defeat means that she's no longer a contender for the world title."*

Comment: Contender is apt, but you need a definition, a source and a link.

Comment: See how I have added definition and examples? You should answer with such details included. :)

Answer (score 0):

That person can be said to be [**"audacious"**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/audacious).

> extremely bold or daring; recklessly brave; fearless:

- **an audacious explorer**,
- **an audacious fighter**,
- **an audacious enterprizer**,
- **an audacious leader**.